# Help me interpret this court record

Tags: court-records

I have a relative who's been dealing with a stalker. The guy has been arrested on stalking charges and is currently in jail. There was an arraignment yesterday and we went in and obtained the public court records for it from the courthouse website. **[Here's the record](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxwhcoiv5ij9uk0/Court%20Info_Redacted.pdf?dl=0)** for reference, redacted for privacy reasons. Just holler if the link doesn't work for some reason.

Overall it's easy to understand. He's been charged with stalking and has entered a plea of not guilty. My questions come down on Page 3 of the PDF.

- What does it mean that there was a motion/order to disqualify the
  judge? The particular judge that was disqualified is the one who
  initially heard my relative when she applied for a protective
  stalking order. Could that be the cause? A different judge ended up
  presiding over the arraignment.
- What does CFW stand for?
- Down near
  the bottom, the arraignment result is listed as "Held." I was
  thinking this meant the defendant is remaining in custody (unless he
  posts bail) until the next hearing on 2/5, but another family member
  interpreted it as just meaning the arraignment took place. Who's
  right?
- Right below that, what does DB stand for?

Thanks for the help! I've tried Googling this information and just get a ton of irrelevant results. The word 'disqualify' shows up in a ton of court records and the abbreviations bring up stuff that's even more off-base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of reasons a judge might be disqualified. It could be that the judge was previous an attorney who represented someone (defendant, victim, key witness) involved in the case, it could be that the judge was a family member or former employer of the defense attorney, it could be that someone close to the judge or the judge personally was a victim of another crime committed by the person, it could be that the defendant or the defendant's family was a personal or family friend. The prior involvement in the protective order case could be a factor as well. The record isn't detailed enough to know.

"Held" in this context means that the hearing scheduled for 1:30 p.m. on that date noted was actually conducted, rather than being continued or vacated for some reason.

Your guess is as good as mine regarding "CFW" and "DB" in this context. My best guess for DB is "daily booking" and CFW might be either the removed or replacement judge's initials (e.g. Carol Francis Wilson) but those are just wild guesses. Neither appears on a list of [Oregon Department of Corrections acryomns](http://www.oregon.gov/doc/docs/pdf/doc_acronyms.pdf) or this [criminal background check abbreviation list](http://www.criminalbackgroundrecords.com/glossary-abbreviations-criminal-background-check.html), or [this list](https://www.portlandoregon.gov/police/article/597513) of Oregon law enforcement abbreviations. The only matches on this [list of law enforcement abbreviations](https://www.accuracyproject.org/PoliceAbbreviationsandAcronyms-US.html) and none of the matches to DB (dog bite, dead body, detective bureau) make a lot of sense in this context.

Comment: Oooooh, I'll bet CFW *is* the judge's initials. That totally makes sense. But yeah, I ran into the same problem looking when trying to look up the acronyms. Anyway, thanks for the response!

Comment: "Denied bail", or "determined bail", or "determined bond" would all make sense at an arraignment.

Comment: That makes sense! It’s probably not “denied” because we know a bail was set, but it could definitely be those other two options.